# 1X2 formula using IF & AND nesting in Open Office Calc for football world cup?

Tags: excel-formula, spreadsheet, nested

It is FIFA world cup time and need some help with my spread sheet project.

We have betting of every game result. Every guy/grl in our betting pool gets points as followed:

- 1 point for guessing home score right
- 1 point for guessing away score right
- 1 point for guessinf winner (1X2) right.

Every guy/grl has his/her own tab in the spreadsheet in which their betting (scores) are inserted in rows like

1-0
1-1
2-4
3-2 ect...

There is one tab to which I enter the actual score as the games are played. These are the real score from which the "logic" checks that how player should be awarded with points.

After hours of inconclusive thinking my question is that how can I make formula that gives me one (1) point, if player guesses the winner corectly (home wins, away wins or the game is tie)?

I already have have system, where I get point for guessing score correctly (if u guess home goals = 1 point and away goals = 1 point, i use formula =IF(EXACT(D2;REALFOOTBALLSCORE.D4);1;0)), but I need one for telling me, that am I rewarded one point for guessing the winner (1X2) or not. I think that in case to do so, I need to play with IF AND nesting. So simplified: what formula tells me that did I guess the winner (1X2) correctly?

Result can also be TRUE or FALSE. The only important thing is, that I get an result of that will I get that one point for 1X2 or not. I use SUM to calculate all points together. It doesn't need to look cool. I hide all the numbers to bottom of the document, where nobody can see them.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I used this formula which also accounts for correctly forecasting a draw as a point:

```
=IF(OR(Results!F7="",Results!G7=""),"",IF(F7=Results!F7,1,0)+IF(G7=Results!G7,1,0)+IF(OR(AND(F7>G7,Results!F7>Results!G7),AND(F7<G7,Results!F7<Results!G7),AND(F7=G7,Results!F7=Results!G7)),1,0))
```

I actually built a version that you might find helpful as a starter:
http://we.tl/vHn90XwBTi

You'll need to figure out what you want to do for the knockout stages. If you're only focused on 90min results, just fill down for the remaining fixtures.

Enjoy the world cup!

Basil

Comment: Just the thing that i was looking for. Just perfect. Just perfect! Thank you so much. I'll just edit this one to make it pefect for our contest!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help. Enjoy the tournament and good luck in your competition!